# How do I implement ISpecifyPropertyPages in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, com, directshow, directshow.net

I'm trying to add a few custom tab pages to the property pages of a DirectShow filter (which I displayed using `OleCreatePropertyFrame`).

Is implementing `ISpecifyPropertyPages` the correct way to do this? If so, how do I do this in C#? Namely, what do I do in the `GetPages` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ISpecifyPropertyPages` is the interface which is used to expose/discover the property page applicable to the object. Its `GetPages` method list the pages that belong to the instance in question.

In your case you not only should implement this interface and method (see [example and related discussion](http://frederickkoh.sys-con.com/node/1545062/mobile)), but you also need to implement the property page itself. DirectShow.NET does not offer you a base for reuse (in C++ development you have two of these: DirectShow BaseClasses offer property page base, and so does ATL), so you need to implement it from scratch. This [C# code snippet](https://web.archive.org/web/20160602021311/http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/4A772A27/53864D4E) looks like a good start.

Comment: Unfortunately your links are no longer available.

Comment: @Robinson: fixed second link, however the first is indeed gone...